# Firebase Database 'Strong' rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

All,

I have been working on an Android App that uses firebase realtime database, cloud store and authentication. It's never going into production on the google play store - however I am worried that in a few days time, the access to the database will be denied because I don't have 'strong' rules - whatever 'strong' are.

Currently, the rules are set as follows:

```
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

The database and all functionality work great - what can i do to add to these rules to satisfy firebase that I now have 'Strong' rules - or at least prevent access from being denied in 30 days - as I need this app to show the functionality of the database etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Automatically when you change your Firebase rules it will be propagated throughout all the database, there is no need for users to update your app, what you need to be sure is that the users have any login provider (google,facebook) because these rules are saying that only authenticated users can read and write into the database.

If you post this rules without an authentication provider from Firebase, your users will see a blank screen and they will not be able to read/write, if you have implemented a login system with any provider you would be fine

Comment: Thank you - this does not answer my question.

The original question mentions these rules work fine.

Firebase is going to give an error saying that these are not 'strong rules' and that access will be denied. I am happy with how all this is working and haven't got the time (deadline is soon) to change the structure of the app etc. just to satisfy these 'strong' rules Is there a way I can extend the access to this beyond the Firebase 30 day limit?

Comment: If you recently changed this rules, give firebase a 24hs span, maybe it sended to you the email before updating the rules in the server , I have this exact same rules and I dont have the warning , the 30 day limit is not there anymore so you dont need to worry about it